# Как дополнить запрос Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Есть запрос как его дополнить?

```
SELECT room, COUNT(*)
FROM `User`
WHERE `sex`=$user1->sex
GROUP BY `room` HAVING COUNT(*) < 12 AND `room` >999
```

Нужно дополнительно получить где sex=2 меньше 5 как данный запрос дополнить?
Под запросом делать если да то как?

Comment: А что должно быть меньше 5, когда sex=2 ? И почему вы считаете, что надо делать что то под запросом. Условия все таки обычно накладываются в where или having, в зависимости от назначения. Кстати, room > 999 стоит проверять в where. А то получается что сначала вы берете все room, группируете их (самая тяжелая операция), а потом половину выбрасываете за ненадобностью

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT sex, room, COUNT(*) as count
FROM `User`
WHERE `room` > 999 AND (`sex`= $user1->sex OR `sex` = 2)
GROUP BY `sex`, `room` 
HAVING if(`sex` = $user1->sex, count < 12, count < 5)
```